# Could not Build Tomcat 7.0.43 "Some input files use or override a deprecated API"

Tags: tomcat, servlets, ant, tomcat7

using Ubuntu 12.04LTS and

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

I get the following error while building the source. JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64

What I did was:

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/
cd trunk
ant
```

Build said success but shows the following error:

```
ompile-java6:
    [javac] Compiling 1313 source files to /root/trunk/output/classes
    [javac] /root/trunk/java/javax/el/ResourceBundleELResolver.java:109: warning: getFeatureDescriptors(javax.el.ELContext,java.lang.Object) in javax.el.ResourceBundleELResolver overrides getFeatureDescriptors(javax.el.ELContext,java.lang.Object) in javax.el.ELResolver; return type requires unchecked conversion
    [javac] found   : java.util.Iterator
    [javac] required: java.util.Iterator<java.beans.FeatureDescriptor>
    [javac]     public Iterator getFeatureDescriptors(
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 1 warning
```

How can I solve this warning?

Comment: You can resolve the warning by changing the Tomcat source code...

Comment: @home what do I have to change?

Comment: Why do you want to change the Tomcat source, it's just a compiler warning? If you really want to change it, just open the File in your favorite IDE - it explains the warning.

Comment: @home Tomcat 7.0.42 has a bug in its websocket source which is fixed in Tomcat 7.0.43dev. Which file should I open?

Comment: How about `ResourceBundleELResolver.java`?

Comment: what should I do with that file?

Comment: I'd rather do not anything with it as it is just a *warning*. If you really want to modify it, just remove the warning (ask your IDE)...